# Standard way to query elasticsearch from webpage

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I want to provide something like a search engine for data I store in elasticsearch.

What is the standard way to provide a search interface to the public, just putting the input from the website into a search query like the following seems not good.

```
s = Search(using=client, index="ie_datablocks") \
    .query("match", text=<INPUT HERE>)
```

What I'd like to provide are search features as e.g., used in kibana (just the querying not the GUI)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you met [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) ?  Fluff, fluff, fluff.

Comment: Nope never heard of that one before (I am very new to elasticsearch) but I will check it out. Thank you